# When a VARCHAR contains a Decimal, you can't convert it to an INT -- Why?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I ran into a problem with SQL code trying to cast/convert a varchar to an int.  Here's a Transact SQL snippet that demonstrates the problem.

```
declare     @code       varchar(100),
            @retCode    smallint,
            @intCode    int

select @retCode =   0, @code = '1.0000            '

select @intCode = convert(int, LTRIM(RTRIM(@code)))
```

You get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.0000' to data type int.

Apparently the `convert` (and `cast`) cannot handle the conversion of a `varchar` decimal value directly to an `int`.

I have had to do this to correct it.

```
declare @code       varchar(100),
    @retCode    smallint,
    @intCode    decimal

select @retCode =   0, @code = '1.0000            '

select @intCode = convert(int, (convert(decimal, LTRIM(RTRIM(@code)))))
select @intCode
```

So WHY did the above correction work -- `varchar -> decimal -> int`? Why can't I do a direct conversion from `varchar` regardless of what number value it is in over to `int`? I'd like to understand the reason(s) behind that.  (Ignore the LTRIM/RTRIM above...it's unnecessary).

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, by the way.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, SQL Server is unsure of which type of conversion you are attempting...

You can do an implicit conversion to int by assigning your variable directly:

```
SET @intcode = @Code -- This will Truncate the decimal portion of the number
```

Alternatively, you can do an explicit conversion in SQL Server 2008 using [TRY_CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx):

Like this:

```
select @intCode = convert( int, try_convert( decimal, @code )  )
```

Either way, you're not doing the string manipulation.

Here's a great explanation of implicit vs explicit conversion on Simple Talk:
[here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/data-conversion-in-sql-server/)

Cheers!

Comment: How will this work if said code is in a CASE WHEN logic like the following:  
  
-- SNIP SNIP --  
    where (code_type = 'AGE'  
        and age >= case when dbo.fnIsNumeric(beginning_cd)=1 then convert(int, (convert(decimal, beginning_cd))) 
        else 0 end
    and age <= case when dbo.fnIsNumeric(ending_cd)=1 then convert(int, (convert(decimal, ending_cd)))
        else 999999 end)

Comment: When using a CASE statement, I use the try_convert instead of convert. It's a drop-in replacement...

Comment: The decimal digits are not significant.  We want to drop them off (just an int is fine).